# What does this mean #(?-mix:facebook|twitter)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

What does the expression #(?-mix:facebook|twitter) mean in the following output from rake routes ?

```
user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback  users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook|twitter)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a regular expression snippet and it effectively matches either `facebook` or `twitter` in that position, and is case-sensitive (so won't match `fAcebOOK` or `TWITTER`).

If you want to know more about regular expressions then [start here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @smathy. I still wish to clarify if 'i' stands for case insensitive matching in Ruby, then how come its case sensitive  here.

Comment: Because of the `-` that's saying to switch **off** all the listed options.  So no case-insensitive matching, no multiline matching (has no effect here) and no extended regex (also no effect here).

Comment: I actually thought that '-' might be reversing the effect but had to confirm. Thanks :)

Comment: Confirmation is always better than guesstifukation.